# Meteor 1.0.2 is crashing on simple loop : "Expected tag name after `<`"

Tags: meteor

My Meteor application is crashing and cannot run. The following code breaks it:

```
for (var u = 0; u< 5; u++) {
   console.log(u);
}
```

The error message is:

```
Your app is crashing. Here's the latest log.

Errors prevented startup:

While building the application:
poc.html:67: Expected tag name after `<`
...   for (var u = 0; u< 5; u++) {         c...
                        ^

Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are writing JavaScript code in your HTML document. You should create a `.js` file, e.g. `poc.js`, and put the JavaScript there.